# Using dll-Library in Unity3D for Android Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dll

Is it possible to include .dll files into the android Apk when building a game with Unity3D.

I use the Nvidia Blast Library for my game and it works fine in the editor, but the stuff done with the library doesn't show up when I build the game for Android. The LogCat outputs the error DLLNotFoundException.

I've tried using a link.xml file, but still the same error.

I got access to the Nvidia GameWorks GitHub Repo and I should be able to compile the source code to .so files to make it work 100%, right?

Comment: did you put your dll file into assets/plugins?

Comment: yes. I tried assets/plugins and assets/plugins/android - both didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it's possible because in my current project I use multiple external dll.

my link.xml file is like this:

```
<linker>
    <assembly fullname="MegaApiClient"> // the name of the assembly
        <type fullname="CG.Web.MegaApiClient.*" preserve="all"/> // excludes all namespaces and classes recursively under MyNamespace
    </assembly>
</linker>
```

preserve="all" was because with the new il2cpp compiler can automatically strip some "not necessary code" (in my case it was a getter/setter and it was necessary).

Comment: Thanks your for answer, two more questions: The fullname of the assembly could be anything and the fullname of the type is the namespace of the dll file, correct?

I've read of the il2cpp compiler. Do i have to seperatly install that to unity?

Comment: the assembly fullname should be the name of the file (if I remember correctly, I've done it some months ago), the name of the namespace it's the same that you import in the Unity class to use you dll library so yes. No you don't have to install it separatly but you can also use the old Mono compiler if you want from the build settings (right now... it will be removed some time in the future). I suggest to just solve the problem with IL2CPP compiler (also check if you are using it right now, just to be sure).

Comment: mh i followed everything you said and switched to the IL2CPP compiler, but still get the DllNotFoundException. I even read the whole NvidiaBlast Documentation to be sure to have the right namespaces, but still. Is it normal, that there are no nvidia-blast files in the lib directory of the Apk, when I open it with WinRAR? Unity compiled a long time at first and was stuck at Stripping Assemblys - I thought that was a good sign, but seems not to mean anything

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure either. I never used NvidiaBlast. The Stripping Assemblys part will always be long because the IL2CPP compiler is slower than Mono (because it compile everything in c++ ahead of time).